# Why TCP client can't detect server closed using write?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am building an IM application, from the client side, I write my code like this (I use SocketChannel in blocking mode, history reason, I think it is not related to this problem):

```
try {
    LogUtil.info(TAG, this.label + " tryConnect, attempt = " + (3 - retry));
    clientChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    clientChannel.configureBlocking(true);
    clientChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(100);
    clientChannel.socket().setTrafficClass(0x10);
    clientChannel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
    clientChannel.socket().setPerformancePreferences(3, 3, 1);
    clientChannel.socket().connect(address, 10000);
    LogUtil.info(TAG, this.label + " socket connected successfully");
    break;
} catch (AlreadyConnectedException ace) {
    LogUtil.info(TAG, label + " AlreadyConnectedException");
    break;
} catch (NotYetConnectedException ace) {
    LogUtil.info(TAG, label + " NotYetConnectedException");
    break;
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    LogUtil.info(TAG, label + " SocketTimeoutException");
    break;
} catch (Exception e) {
    clientChannel = null;
    throw new SocketConnectionException(label + ", exception = " + ThrowableUtil.stackTraceToString(e));
}
```

The problem is, when sometimes I shut down the server, the client-side will keeps writing successfully (small chunks of data, less than 50 bytes in total). After about 3 minutes, the client side hits the write fail exception.

Why didn't the client side fail immediately after the server has been closed? How do I fix this problem? Maybe reduce the send buffer to 10 bytes ?

#### EDIT

Here's how I actually write data:

```
public void writeXML(ByteBuffer buffer, int retry) {
        synchronized (writeLock) {
            if (retry < 0) {
                throw new SocketConnectionException(label + "Write Exception");
            }
            tryConnect(false);
            try {
                int written = 0;
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    // I think it should be an exception here after I closed server
                    written += clientChannel.write(buffer);
                }
                if (LogUtil.debug) {
                    LogUtil.info(TAG, "\t successfully written = " + written);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tryConnect(true);
                writeXML(buffer, --retry);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have some ideas, but there's not enough to go on.  The code you have provided is just the connection code. Can you show your code code that actually writes to the socket, where you expected the socket exception to happen, and where it's finally occurring at.

Comment: @selbie Thanks, I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Because in between you and the peer application there are:

- a socket send buffer
- a TCP implementation
- another TCP implementation
- a socket receive buffer.

Normally when you write, the data just gets transferred into your socket send buffer and is sent on the wire asynchronously. So if there is going to be an error sending it you won't find out straight away. You will only find out when the TCP sends have failed enough times over whatever the internal send timeout period is for TCP to decide that an error condition exists. The next write (or read) after *that* will get the error. It could be some minutes away.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but is there any way to make this period shorter? And in my case, the error didn't come after the next write, it comes after quite a few writes(though those write a pretty short, like 10 bytes for each)

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that the `read` operation can detect a closed connection(via @EJP's reply, it is different from a lost connection) immediately.

In my reading thread, I have this line:

```
int read = clientChannel.read(buffer);
```

, When it returns `-1` means the server is shutdown (Shutdown on purpose is different than network unreachable), I guess the `write` operation needs to fill the TCP send buffer, so there's no way to detect a connection lost quickly.

Comment: `read()` returning -1 is not a 'lost connection', it is a *closed* connection. If you're writing to a closed connection you have an error in your application protocol.

Comment: @EJP In my case, it is a closed connection (server shutdown on purpose), I misunderstand it before, will update my answer.